# Create a localDB and use it when SQL server is down

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need your help to manage an issue with my C# program. I wrote a GUI that allows the user to manage a lot of data stored in a SQL Server database. Everything works fine but I want to be sure that the application works even when the server is down (for a generic issue).

My plan is to have a local database (e.g. `*.mdf` database used in Visual Studio) and update it every time the GUI is able to connect to the online SQL Server database.

What do you think? Is there something similar to a procedure or do I need to do it manually (create a `.mdf` file, check the online version, write the changes etc.)?

Comment: I don't thinks this is a good idea, you will have partial datas and divergent informations on each

Comment: Is this a single-user program, or a multi-user (where more than one person might be updating the same data?)

Comment: You need to look into some of the High Availability Solutions for sql server, localDb is not an answer to tackle this issue, google Sql Server Fail Over Cluster, Mirroring , Replication and Log shipping. If your company is willing to spend some money Fail over cluster is the way to go. If you are on Sql Server 2012 or later version also look into High Availability groups.

Comment: Dear all, thank you very much for your comments. The application is multi-user and the local solution is only to be sure to read data when server is down. My idea is to use primary the one online, check if the local is older than the first and update the local. I want to have the local "only for reading".

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the comments noting that this may not be a good idea (which I agree):

- Most of the work must be done manually. If you have a DB model within your application (like when using entity framework) it could be that it can create the DB structure in the local file. Most of your data will need timestamps to determine when they were changed the last time.
- The Microsoft Sync Framework might utilize you but I have not used it personally. Look here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)